# uWSGI+Flask+boto - thread safety

Tags: python, flask, boto, uwsgi

Say I have a Flask application, served by uWSGI using multiple processes, like:

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:3031 --file flaskapp.py --callable app --processes 4
```

And my Flask app is organized like this:

```
/flaskapp
    app.py
    /db
        __init__.py
        somefile.py
        somefile2.py
        ...
```

And I'm using boto to connect to DynamoDB. The `__init__.py` file is empty, and each `somefilexxx.py` file  begins something like this:

```
db = boto.connect_dynamodb()
table = db.get_table('table')
def do_stuff_with_table():
```

I don't use threads in the app, and I don't think uWSGI uses threads unless I explicitly enable them with `--threads`. Does this setup make sense? Are there any threading issues I have to worry about with urllib (you might guess I know less than nothing about threads...)?

Alternatively, would it make more sense to call `connect_dynamodb()` in the `__init__.py` file and only load the tables in the `somefile.py` files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you haven't enabled threads in uWSGI (see: `--enable-threads`, `--threads`) there's no Python threading going on here (in Boto or otherwise.)

I would recommend using `--lazy`, which will cause your app to be loaded in each worker post-fork. Then you can simply rely on that behavior to ensure each worker has the appropriate connections/pools/etc. available without the concerns of shared state.