# Why does not uWSGI work with boto3? Respawned uWSGI worker

Tags: python, boto3, uwsgi, wsgi

When I import boto3, uWSGI does not work. Without boto3, it works smoothly.

```
...

from flask import Flask

import boto3

app = Flask(__name__)

...
```

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
socket = :8010
module = main
callable = app
protocol = http
master = true
```

error: DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: x) died, killed by signal 6 :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: x)

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Possible fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11666677/2052575