# Creating a single connection that persists for multiple view method calls in Django?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto

I have a method 'upload' in views.py which is called when a user goes to www.website.com/upload/data. In this method, I create a connection to amazon S3 and then upload data.

But the problem is that this upload method will be called hundreds of times every minute.
So, It will be very wasteful to create a new S3 connection every time.

I just want to create one connection that persists for all the separate method calls of upload.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boto has built-in connection pooling and relies on HTTP Keep-Alive feature. So you should be ok.

Source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/boto-users/O2cae4Rnsps/b8O53OakoSoJ

A related StackOverflow question: [Boto connect_xxx method and connection pools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622548/boto-connect-xxx-method-and-connection-pools)