# Boto RequestExpired

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

When running long processes I keep getting:

```
...
content_repl/replicate_content.py", line 667, in detach_and_delete
    volumes = ec2_conn.get_all_volumes(volume_ids=volumes_ids)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 2158, in get_all_volumes
    [('item', Volume)], verb='POST')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1186, in get_list
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>RequestExpired</Code><Message>Request has expired.</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>xxxxxxxx</RequestID></Response>
```

Note that many operations are performed along the script without problems.
At the beginning of the script I have:

```
ec2_conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(AWS_REGION,
  aws_access_key_id=assumedRoleObject.credentials.access_key,
  aws_secret_access_key=assumedRoleObject.credentials.secret_key,
  security_token=assumedRoleObject.credentials.session_token,proxy=PROXY,proxy_por=PROXY_PORT)
```

Reading [Boto connect_xxx method and connection pools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622548/boto-connect-xxx-method-and-connection-pools) and Boto docs my understanding is that Boto should handle connections internally and get a new one when needed. Is that correct? Should I add a parameter for that? Implement some retry logic myself?

Btw, I'm using v2.40.
The app is single threaded.

Comment: Have you checked the time on that computer to see if it is accurate? Requests have a timestamp to prevent replay attacks, so I'm wondering if that might be the cause of the "expiry" message?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have, this is why I mentioned that many operations were performed before. I think indeed the problem is the timeout, but seems it is a problem I shouldn't have if connections are handled automatically.

Comment: Examine the contents of the response from `assumedRoleObject.credentials.session_token`.  Tokens expire.  Not sure if this is the message you would receive if that is the problem, but they do expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that in the end the problem was just with the connection object. According to my testing the assumedRoleObject could be reused without problems. Just in case however, I've recreated that object too when I recreate the connection.

Connections are good for 1 hour, then they start failing.